# Is someone using my @domain.com emails for fraud?

Tags: email, fraud, dns-domain

I have a TLD, and have set it up to forward any email sent to `*@domain.com` to `myname@domain.com`.

Over the last week, I've got a handful of emails from Intuit/TurboTax to random names on my domain, e.g. `lucie@domain.com`, and they seem legitimate (pass SPF/DKIM/DMARC).

The emails include full names, billing addresses, last 4 digits of card numbers and licence keys for turbotax, which all seem to be legitimate too.

The domain is *quite* obscure, and this has now happened 5+ times. I don't see any way that this could be a mistake. My best guess is that it's some sort of fraud attempt.

Is this a "known" type of fraud?

I'd like to avoid any potential association with it, and it's also just a bit of a nuisance. Is there anything I can do or anyone I should contact in this situation?

Comment: Contact turbotax since there appear to be license keys

Comment: This sounds similar to the Netflix scam of a couple of years ago (see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/210045/why-would-someone-open-a-netflix-account-using-my-gmail-address).  With tax season coming up, it may be that someone is recycling this scam and using it for Intuit and/or TurboTax, instead of Netflix.

Comment: "I have a TLD" I doubt so. You have a domain name, not a TLD.